# Trouble in passing value of 'value = ' attr (PHP)

Tags: php, html, post

Is it possible to pass value from 'value' attr to the php code? 
My html is like this:

```
<label for='pname'>Order Product:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="pname" value="<?php echo $orderproduct; ?>" disabled>
```

And at the server side its:

```
if(empty($_POST['pname'])  ||
   empty($_POST['quantity'])  || 
   empty($_POST['cname'])  || 
   empty($_POST['name'])  ||
   empty($_POST['address'])  ||
   empty($_POST['number'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
$cname = $_POST['cname']; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$number = $_POST['number']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

I dont want the user to edit the Order Product data field! And the output I am getting is:

**Error: all fields are required**

I am getting the rest value through the post session! but not **'pname'** value! 
I tired using $_SESSION instead of $_POST, still doesnt work.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`.  What does it show?

Comment: how are you submitting your form? did you check if a POST is even being performed?

Comment: Where the variable $orderproduct is coming from?

Comment: MarcB, yaa all POST are accepted except the pname!
Mr.Llama, Ill check and let u know
WilliamJanoti, It is string type variable.. the name of the product, the user orders!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disabled tags are not submitted so you will not receive this in the POST**

You can create this tag as hidden if you do not want to display it, by adding `type="hidden"`

And in case you want to display it but in non-editable state then add `readonly` in tag.

Comment: Ok wait I will check it! my internet is kind of slow!